# What is sequential change point detection?

Tags: change-point

Could someone point me to an introductory-level explanation (think Wikipedia entry) of what sequential change point detection is?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.research.ibm.com/PM/sigt98.ps and http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~liu32/cs599/Time_series.pdf

Comment: @Shai: I'm not familiar with this topic, so I'd like to ask your advice: do you think it would be appropriate to migrate this question to stats.SE?

Comment: @Zev: I am also not familiar with this topic, but it is evident from the content of the linked document entitled "An Introduction to Change-Point Detection" (the .ps file) that, indeed, it would be appropriate to migrate this question to stats.SE.

Answer (score 5):

In a nutshell, change detection is the problem of determining changes in the distribution of a stochastic process when the decision is made as observations arrive.

The relevant Wikipedia article is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection).